# Hide/Show specific divs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make an HTML element reference like this

```
<html>        X
- description -

<head>        X
- description -

<body>        X
- description -
```

The description of the element is hidden by default so when I click on the "X" or the DIV that contains that element description, the description shows up or hide when I click it again.

This is my HTML code:

```
<h1>HTML Reference</h1>
  <div id="reference-list">
      <div class="list-element">&lt;html&gt;</div>
      <div class="element-desc">Here's go description</div>
      <div class="list-element">&lt;head&gt;</div>
      <div class="element-desc">Here's go description</div>
  </div>
```

I tried with jQuery but I dont know how to select the specific div containing the description of that element, since all the divs have the same class (otherwise I will have to create 100 class for each HTML element).

What I tried is this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list-element").click(function(){
        $(".element-desc").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

This doesn't work since it show/hide the description of all the elements on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.next()` if thats is the correct position of your element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list-element").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>HTML Reference</h1>
  <div id="reference-list">
      <div class="list-element">&lt;html&gt;</div>
      <div class="element-desc">Here's go description</div>
      <div class="list-element">&lt;head&gt;</div>
      <div class="element-desc">Here's go description</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see... that worked, it was really easy, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting all the element descriptions with the `$(".element-desc")` selector. Try doing this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list-element").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Using `next` selects the next element. Basically you want to make your selector more specific and using `next` is one example of how to do so

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sure! @Shipwreck would you please mind marking the correct answer (either mine or the other answer) as correct? Thanks!

Comment: I marked the other one because is the first one that I saw, but both of you were very helpful :) thanks again!